# How to use LC_MESSAGES=C with gcc every time?

Tags: linux, gcc, localization, locale

Currently I'm using Ubuntu with my system locale and language set to Japanese. However I'd like to have it always displaying gcc messages in English as it would be easier for me.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869309/selecting-message-language-in-gcc-and-g) if I did `~$ LC_MESSAGES=C gcc` it displays in English. How can I make it so it's always like this without entering in `~$ LC_MESSAGES=C gcc` every time and without changing my system language? All I want changed is "gcc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an alias in your shell.

```
alias gcc="LC_MESSAGES=C \gcc"
```

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with an alias will be that they don't transfer to things like `make` very reliably.  If I needed to do it, I'd probably create a shell script called `gcc` in my `$HOME/bin` directory which would set the environment variable and execute the 'real' `gcc`.  My own `bin` directory is always on my PATH ahead of system directories.  Hence:

```
LC_MESSAGES=C exec /usr/gcc/v4.7.1/bin/gcc "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting LC_MESSAGES=C in your users ~/.profile

```
export LC_MESSAGES=C
```

EDIT
 Yeah don't use that it will change LC_MESSAES locale for all applications under your user that use it. Credit to [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams)

Comment: "... and without changing my system language?"

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  ...yeah you're right. It will affect more then just gcc messages for this user. However it doesn't change the overall systems language.